# String Interpolation Of Version

Tags: vb.net

I've been converting some code to use string interpolation instead of concatenation but have hit an anomaly with the `Version` property.

This works as expected:

```
Dim CurrTime As String = $"Current time is {Now:HH:mm:ss}" (eg Current time is 23:22:21)
```

But this doesn't:

```
Dim Ver As String = $"Version is {myAssembly.GetName().Version:3}"
```

If `Version` is, say, 1.2.3.4, Ver still resolves to "Version is 1.2.3.4" instead of "Version is 1.2.3" as I would expect.

Am I misinterpreting how this should work? Obviously, it's not a big deal, I'm just confused.

Comment: What formatting type is `:3`? Note that you have `Version.Tostring()` there. Maybe you want to use its components instead.

Comment: @Jimi You mean that I can use `.ToString(3)`? Yes, I can - and currently do - but I'm asking why `.Version:3` doesn't work. `:3` should equate to `.ToString(3)`, I would think, just as `:HH:mm:ss` equates to `ToString("HH:mm:ss")`. BTW, there is no compiler error, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: The Version class overloads `ToString()` to provide field count functionality. See public [String ToString(int fieldCount)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/version.cs,278). `:3` is not a recognized format specifier for strings (as mentioned, in your code you have `Version.ToString()`, not `Version.ToString([int fieldCount])` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:formatString` part used in composite formatting (e.g., with string interpolation or `String.Format()`) does *not* do everything that `ToString()` does. The former only supports certain types. If you check the docs for [Structure of an interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#structure-of-an-interpolated-string), you'll see that description of the `formatString` element is:

> A format string that is supported by the type of the expression result. For more information, see [Format String Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#format-string-component).

And if you follow the link, it takes you to the documentation of composite formatting where you can read more about what types are supported:

> The optional formatString component is a format string that is appropriate for the type of object being formatted. Specify a standard or custom numeric format string if the corresponding object is a numeric value, a standard or custom date and time format string if the corresponding object is a DateTime object, or an enumeration format string if the corresponding object is an enumeration value. If formatString is not specified, the general ("G") format specifier for a numeric, date and time, or enumeration type is used. The colon is required if formatString is specified.

As a workaround, you could combine `String.Format()` with string interpolation:

```
Dim Ver As String = $"Version is {myAssembly.GetName().Version.ToString(3)}"
```

Or just revert to concatenation for this specific case.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Interesting that there is no compiler bleating, the formatting is just ignored.